# Animated Gif's for user content

Tags: support, status-completed

I have some tie rod rotation images I wanted to upload for an upcoming question. Does stack exchange support animated gifs for user content in Questions and Answers? I'll find out soon enough I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes

You can put animated gif's in your post and they will function normally

Comment: Very cool, looks like I have to downsize the guys. Turns out image magic does some magic for me! Just had to name my files something like `tr00.jpg, tr01.jpg...`, then I run the command `convert  -resize 28% -delay 20   -loop 0   *.jpg   tieRodRotations.gif` and voila!